# Using awk how to compare 2 fields and print something out

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

Let say I have `file1` with the following content:

```
1,2,3,4,12,6
1,2,3,5,333,6
1,2,3,12,5,6
1,2,3,44,101,6
```

While `file2` has the following content:

```
22,4,111,1,6,7,12
22,4,56,55,6,7,12
22,4,12,12,6,7,12
22,4,333,102,6,7,12
```

What I want is if `5th` field on `file1` has a greater value than the `3rd` field on `file2` print something like `Value 333 greater than 56`

How could this be done using awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'FILENAME=="file1" {inputs[FNR]=$5} FILENAME=="file2" && inputs[FNR] > $3 {print inputs[FNR] " is greater than " $3 " on line " FNR}' file1 file2
333 is greater than 56 on line 2
```

Comment: Great! @DopeGhoti. Could you please explain what is going on?  Why do you use e.g `FILENAME=="file2" && inputs[FNR]`  here the `&&` and by the first `FILENAME=="file1"` you are not. Thanks! It works

Comment: The code populates an array only when reading `file1`.  It makes the comparison only when reading `file2` and only prints the output when the comparison matches the specified criterium.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below method to get the same required output

```
for i in {1..4}; do second_file=`awk -F "," -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $3}' j.txt`; first_file=`awk -F "," -v i="$i" 'NR==i {print $5}' l.txt`; if [[ $first_file -gt  $second_file ]]; then echo $first_file is greater than $second_file; fi; done
```

output

```
333 is greater than 56
```